# REGEXP_EXTRACT in Google Data Studio; Keep Getting 'Null'

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am creating reports in Google's Data Studio, and I have successfully created several custom dimensions in the past using `REGEXP_MATCH` on the `Keyword` dimension combined with `CASE` statements to create the dimensions I need.  This one has me stumped.

I have data coming in through the `Keyword` dimension that contains a substring that I would like to extract and display as a custom dimension.

A subset of the keyword data coming through looks like this:

```
09172018_rp_ws_1_og_
img s4_ac_p_act_
img s5_ws_5_m_
img s4_ws_5_m_
```

I am trying to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to create a new calculated field called `Image type` that is a dimension that groups all entries with starting with img, followed by a space, and then any alphanumeric afterwards ending with an underscore.   So all entries with `img s4` would be grouped together, `img s5` would be grouped together.  Anything in the keyword dimension without that pattern can be left out of the dataset entirely.

I am not able to get any results except `null` using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`.

Even just trying `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, '.*img.*')` yields null when entering in the formula for the new calculated field.

What is stumping me is I tried the following just to see if my syntax was off, and this formula does return results (just not what I want as the image types are not aggregated).

```
CASE
  WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH(Keyword, '.*img.*')) THEN Keyword
  ELSE "Not Set"
END
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?  I can't get any output out of `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, 'your reg expression here')` no matter what I enter.

Comment: Try `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, 'img ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)')`. Also, try `'img\\s+(\\w+)'`

Comment: Both of those were close - thank you!  They didn't strip out the rest of the data after encountering the first "_", but they did return data.  I tried:  REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, '^(img .+?_)') and that worked - something about that first ^.  I think it's time to study up on my RE2 regex expressions.

Comment: So, what is the rule then? `img` at the beginning, then 1+ whitespace and then all up to the first .... What char?  Or up to the end of the line? Like `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, 'img\\s+(.+)')`? See https://regex101.com/r/5y893C/2

Comment: img is at the beginning in all of the cases I have seen, but in the future I believe it might be found in the middle of the keyword string, so I was hoping to find this string "img<space><anynumberof alphanumeric characters here><underscore>" and extract that from anywhere in the original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind that in order to extract any text from `REGEXP_EXTRACT`, you should define a *capturing group* inside the regex pattern. In short, enclose the part you need to extract with a pair of unescaped parentheses.

Now, to match `img` at the start of the string you need to use `^` anchor, it matches the start of a string position.

To match 1 or more chars, use `+`.

So, you may use any of the following depending on your actual rules:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, '^img ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, '^img\\s+(\\w+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Keyword, '^img\\s+(.+)')
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `img`  - a literal substring
- `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars: letters, digits or `_`
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars.